# Cygwin Newbie: How do I uninstall Python 2.6.x from Cygwin and install Python 2.7.x?

Tags: python, windows-7, cygwin, 64-bit

I am trying to run a Python script on a Windows 7-64 bit machine using Cygwin. I can't get the newest version of Python installed in this environment.

Question:

- How do I uninstall Python 2.6
- Which Python package should I use for Cygwin?

Answer (score 6):

To uninstall the Python interpreter (or any other package) from Cygwin:

- Run the `setup.exe` file (the one you downloaded for installing Cygwin)
- Make sure the installation folder matches your Cygwin location
- On the package selection screen, find the package you want to uninstall (here `python`)
- Change its state from `keep` to `uninstall` by clicking on it 3 times
- Click next to begin the uninstallation

At the moment, Python 2.7 has not been ported to Cygwin. The latest Python 2 version is `2.6.8-2`.
However, Python 3.2 has been ported, so you should check if your script is compatible with it.

You can have Python 2 and 3 installed at the same time on Cygwin – the first can be fired with the classic `python` command, and the latter with `python3`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I apologize for not replying last year! :)

Comment: Is there a reason the installation folder has to match the Cygwin location? Mine has been at the default location ever since I installed Cygwin, which is `User\My Documents\Cygwin Installation`, on a completely separate drive to the actual Cygwin installation.